# how to make a table with multiple selection and generic, using Titem in blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor-webassembly

I want to make a `table component`, using Titem that is reusable with multiple selection, I managed to do the multiple selection but I can't make the `component reusable`, any advice?
I have a reusable table that I made by viewing this direct example from microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0
this is my code:

```
@page "/multiple"

<div class="table-responsive">

    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (valueList != null)
            {
                int count = valueList.Count;
                for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    int current = i; // don't use loop variable in binding
                    var values = valueList[current];

                    <tr class="@values.Class" @onclick="((e) => SelectItems(current, true))">
                        <td>@values.Name</td>
                        <td>@values.Age</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>

        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" @onclick="showSelected">Click</button>

<hr />
@if (events != null)
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var evt in events)
        {
            <li>@evt</li>
        }
    </ul>
}

@code
{
    //Declare various lists and classes.
    private List<Value> valueList;
    private List<string> events = new List<string>();

    class Value
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
        public string Class { get; set; }
    }

    //OnInitialized function to instantiated the valueList.
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        valueList = new List<Value>();
        valueList.Add(new Value()
        {
            Name = "James",
            Age = "38"
        });
        valueList.Add(new Value()
        {
            Name = "John",
            Age = "32"
        });
    }

    //Function to set selected class on tr. Can multi-select or single via Toggle bool.
    void SelectItems(int index, bool toggle)
    {
        var item = valueList[index];

        //If toggle then allow multiple to be selected. If class already selected then clear.
        if (toggle)
        {
            if (item.Class == "selected")
            {
                item.Class = "";
            }
            else
            {
                item.Class = "selected";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var value in valueList)
            {
                value.Class = "";
            }
            // set the value
            item.Class = "selected";
        }
    }

    //Function to show the selected items.
    void showSelected()
    {
        events.Clear();
        foreach (var value in valueList)
        {
            if (value.Class.Contains("selected"))
            {
                events.Add($"'{value.Name}' selected. With value: '{value.Age}'");
            };
        }
    }
}
```

this table is already a reusable component how can I make it multiple selectable:

```
 <table class="@TableClass">
        <thead class="@TheadClass">
            <tr>
                @Cabecera
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in ItemList)
            {
                <tr>@Filas(item)</tr>
            }
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                @Pie
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

@code{

  [Parameter] public string ClassTable { get; set; }
  [Parameter] public string ClassThead { get; set; }
  [Parameter] public RenderFragment Cabecera { get; set; }
  [Parameter] public RenderFragment Pie { get; set; }
  [Parameter] public RenderFragment<TItem> Filas { get; set; }
  [Parameter] public IEnumerable<TItem> Items { get; set; }      
  IEnumerable<TItem> ItemList { get; set; }

  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
   {
      ItemList = Items;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0) said, the templated components are generically typed, then when using the TableTemplated, you could transfer the data from the main page to the TableTemplate component via the template parameters.

Try to use the following code:

TableTemplate.razor:

```
@typeparam TItem

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>@TableHeader</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            <tr>@RowTemplate(item)</tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment TableHeader { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<TItem> RowTemplate { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public IReadOnlyList<TItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Index.razor: here we add onclick event for each cell.

```
<TableTemplate Items="pets" Context="pet">
    <TableHeader>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Class</th>
    </TableHeader>
    <RowTemplate >
        <td @onclick="((e)=>SelectItems(pet.PetId, true))">@pet.PetId</td> 
        <td @onclick="((e)=>SelectItems(pet.PetId, true))">@pet.Name</td>
        <td @onclick="((e)=>SelectItems(pet.PetId, true))">@pet.Class</td>
    </RowTemplate>
</TableTemplate>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" @onclick="showSelected">Click</button>

@code {
    private List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet>()
    {
            new Pet { PetId = 2, Name = "Mr. Bigglesworth"  },
            new Pet { PetId = 4, Name = "Salem Saberhagen" },
            new Pet { PetId = 7, Name = "K-9" }
    };
    private List<string> events = new List<string>();
    private class Pet
    {
        public int PetId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Class { get; set; }
    }
    void SelectItems(int petId, bool toggle)
    {
        var item = pets.Find(c=>c.PetId ==petId);

        //If toggle then allow multiple to be selected. If class already selected then clear.
        if (toggle)
        {
            if (item.Class == "selected")
            {
                item.Class = "";
            }
            else
            {
                item.Class = "selected";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var value in pets)
            {
                value.Class = "";
            }
            // set the value
            item.Class = "selected";
        }
    }
    //Function to show the selected items.
    void showSelected()
    {
        foreach (var value in pets)
        {
            if (value.Class!=null && value.Class.Contains("selected"))
            {
                events.Add($"'{value.Name}' selected. With value: '{value.Name}'");                
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The result as below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help, it worked perfectly for me, just a question, how can I make the selected tr change color?